# Reading surname from US, Massachusetts Boston - Crew Lists, 1917-1943?

Tags: 20th-century, palaeography, indexing, massachusetts

I’m currently indexing records from US, Massachusetts Boston - Crew Lists, 1917-1943.
I’m having trouble reading the surname of a particular crew member.
[image]

As usual with indexing, r, s, u, n, t, w, and m all look very similar. So far I’ve been able to make out most of the names but this one is particularly hard for me. The nationality made out to be Swedish by another Stack Exchange user. Race is listed as Scandinavian.

[image]

Here are some handwriting examples to compare to.

Comment: The nationality looks like 'Swedis' (probably 'Swedish', obviously). Reading the surname would be easier with more examples of the handwriting to compare letter-forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the original images, the nationality looks like '**Swedis**' (probably '**Swedish**', obviously).

[image: Nationality]

---

For the surname, the best fit appears to be "**Nystrom**", although I'd like to see more examples of the letter "t" in the same hand (examples of the combinations "Ny-" and "om" would also be nice, obviously, but when we're transcribing we have to work with what's in front of us). The "r" and "s" match other examples on the form nicely.

The surname [Nystrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nystrom) would also fit quite nicely with the nationality being Swedish.